# packet retransmission when using scp/ssl over wireGuard interface

Tags: networking, ssl, scp, wireguard

I've created wireGuard based network interface on my macOS.

and according to the protocol description, WireGuard is working over UDP.

So I was wondering which layer handle the packets retransmission (in case of network failure) when I use "scp" (which works over ssl) over the WireGuard interface.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I use "scp" (which works over ssl)

No, `scp` works over SSHv2.

> I was wondering which layer handle the packets retransmission (in case of network failure) when I use "scp" over the WireGuard interface.

TCP does.

If SSHv2 is using TCP normally, it'll still be using TCP when carried over WireGuard or any other VPN type – its TCP/IP packets will just go *inside* the WireGuard UDP/IP packets. (WireGuard is a *tunnel* – it results in an additional instance of the same layer, in this case its UDP packets carry IP again.)

The VPN tunnel *may* have its own retransmission as well (I think WireGuard actually does), but that isn't strictly necessary, as the "inner" IP has no expectations about reliability.